# Solving $\frac{\alpha^2}{(t_1-x)^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{(t_2-x)^2}=1$

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions

For a given $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$ and $t_1,t_2>0, t_1\neq t_2$, I'm trying to solve the following equation:
$$\frac{\alpha^2}{(t_1-x)^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{(t_2-x)^2}=1$$
I tried to calculate delta for a forth degree equation but it's too complicated is there a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\alpha^2}{(t_1-x)^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{(t_2-x)^2}=1 \Rightarrow \frac{\alpha^2}{(t_1-x)^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{(t_2-x)^2}= \alpha^2+\beta^2$$

So

$$(t_1-x)^2=1 \text{ and } (t_2-x)^2=1$$

Comment: Why are those ALL solutions?

Comment: If you open an equation that is the fourth degree and find 4 different solutions using $t_1 \neq t_2$. $x \in \{1+t_1, t_1-1, 1+t_2, t_2-1\}$

Comment: Suppose $t_1=5$ and $t_2=1$ then above equations will never be true together (hence, lead to no solution ), but the main equation is degree 4 polynomial so, it must have solutions. Think in a way that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are given than you have to solve for $x$.

Comment: @Lucas The four solutions you posted are solutions to the first equation OR to the second equation. But you need solutions to your first equation AND your second equation, at the same time..Note if $|t_1-t_2|>2$ there is no $x$ such that $$(t_1-x)^2=1 \text{ and } (t_2-x)^2=1$$

Comment: Just to clarify... You claim that $x=1+t_1$ is a solution, therefore it satisfies $$1=(t_2-x)^2=(t_2-1-t_1)^2$$ Why?

Comment: you're right. not enough each equation to be equal to 1. They must be equal.

Comment: @user547654 Did you understand the problem of my solution?